# Reduction order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Good afternoon,

I am going over **reduction of order** method in solving a *second order linear* equation. As show in the example in this link:

[image]

Following the method, I arrived at $w' - w = 0$ which is a *separable function*, however I do not understand that by separating, they obtained $Ct^{1/2}$ as the value of $w(t)$.

I attempted to solve this using integration factor; but in terms of 
$y' + p(t)y = g(t)$,  $g(t)$ equates to $0$.

My goal here is to find $v(t)$ and $w = v'(t)$

Thanks

Comment: They multiplied by the  integrating factor $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ which gave them the equation $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}w)=0$

Comment: @JustinStevenson I used u(t) = e$^{∫p(t)dt}$ but I got e$^{½ln t}$ as integrating factor, but my g(t) is 0; how do I get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$

Comment: Thats almost corect, you are missing a negative sign. Also you just have to remember your logarithm properties. you can bring the $\frac{-1}{2}$ to the exponent and then the $ln$ cancels with the $e$ leaving $t^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

Comment: okay thank very  much @justin

Answer (score 1):

you are supposed to solve $$ 2t w′−w=0 $$ which is separable.

$$\frac {dw}{w} = \frac {dt}{2t}$$
$$\ln w = (1/2) \ln Ct $$

$$ w=Ct^{1/2} $$

The rest follows easily.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Thanks for your attention.